# How do I make my replace code work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a basic replace code that replaces the match every time.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.replace = function(obj) {
        var a = $(this).html();
        for (var i in obj) {
            $(this).html(a.replace(i, obj[i]));
        }
    };
    $('#myDiv').replace({
        ':\)': '<img src="http://bit.ly/dbtoez" />'
    });
})(jQuery);​
```

​But it doesn't work. Also, when I put more properties into the object to replace on the div, it doesn't work. The img element is a smiley face.

Comment: Remember to up vote and accept! Thanks!

Comment: When replacing literal strings, `a.split(search).join(replacement)` is much better than regexps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/kCtLh/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.replace = function(obj) {
        var a = $(this).html();
        for (var i in obj){
           a = a.replace(new RegExp(i.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1"), "g"), obj[i]);
        }
        return $(this).html(a);
    };
})(jQuery);

$('#myDiv').replace({
    ':)': '<img src="http://bit.ly/dbtoez" />'
});​
```

Final Version. It escapes all the characters for you. :)

Comment: Get the latest version. It's even better.

Comment: Never mind. It worked when I doubled escaped the `')'` symbol.

Comment: @David This is the final version. Use this.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically throwing away all replacements but the last one. Modify `a` in your loop and update the HTML at the end:

```
var a = $(this).html();
for (var i in obj) {
    a = a.replace(new RegExp(i, 'g'), obj[i]);
}
$(this).html(a);
```

Comment: This works but how do I make it replace every time it sees the smiley face :) ??

Comment: You need to use a global regexp instead of the string replacement you do right now.

Comment: Do I use that as the name of the property of the object in the `.replace()` call?

Comment: Oh snap, didn't notice it's an object - you probably cannot use a regex object as a property name... I've updated my answer.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /:)/: Unmatched ')'`

Comment: You need to escape the `)` as it has a special meaning in regexps. Use `':\\)'`. You are dealing with a string at this point so you need to escape the backslash to keep it. The `RegExp` constructor will then receive `:\)`.

Comment: Good answer, though it makes escaping quite troublesome.